# How do I choose what format Outlook uses to reply/forward a message?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, formatting

I use HTML-formatted e-mail for internal messages.

When someone external sends me a plaintext message and I forward it internally, Outlook defaults to using plaintext to forward it as well.

Is there any way to make it always use HTML or at least a command I can use to reply to a message using HTML formatting?

I know that I can change the formatting after the reply window opens, but everything remains in plaintext defaults -- default font, signature, etc.

Comment: Molly and John T: Thank you for your answers. I have voted both up for the information. I don't want to install any additional software on my work computer, however.

Answer (score 5):

There is no setting to change the default reply format, Outlook **will always** default to replying in the format of the incoming message. Changing the formatting after the reply window opens is your best bet.

What you could do though is make a hotkey to change the formatting type. [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) is great for this and you don't need to know how to script either. AutoHotkey comes with a tool called AutoScriptWriter which can record a macro for you that you can play back much faster.

Comment: That is so dumb. How are MS so dumb? They have so much money. Mozilla have so much less, and yet Thunderbird has been able to do that since forever.

Comment: @gargoylebident It boggles the mind at how many UX things Microsoft gets wrong like this (what I would call UX anyway).

Answer (score 4):

**Setting the default email format on email replies**

Although Microsoft Outlook allows you to select a default email format when sending new emails, this setting does not apply when replying to email messages. By default, when composing a reply, Outlook will use the email format of the original email. Thus, no matter if your default format for new mail is set to "plain text", if you are replying to a HTML email, your own reply will be generated as a HTML email.

To increase your Outlook productivity, **[Bells & Whistles](http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/outlook-bells.html)** makes it very easy to specify a default email format even when sending replies. As a result, **the selected format will be automatically applied on all your email replies, no matter the format of the original email**.

To use this feature, you have to enable the option "Always reply using..." from the "Reply Options" section of the Bells & Whistles configuration screen, which can be launched from the Outlook -> Tools menu.

[image]

*Bells & Whistles for Outlook is shareware ($29.95), try before you buy.*

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the original email and change the format to the format you want the reply or forward to be in. This is better than changing the format after hitting *Reply/Forward* **as it keeps all of the existing formatting that is otherwise lost** once you hit the *Reply/Forward* button.

Under the *Message* Tab select **Other Actions->Edit Message** (This can be added to the Quick Bar). This gives you the *Insert/Options/Format Text* tabs for the current message. Then under *Options* select **HTML/Rich Text**, and then *Reply/Forward* as desired.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that this must be done individually for every message one is replying to or forwarding? If so, I don't see how this is any better than changing the format of the reply message every time.

Comment: How can a plaintext message keep all the formatting? Or does this then reformat it back to HTML? In that case, this is horrible and useless.

Answer (score 2):

At least you can add a shortcut to the Quick Access Toolbar for HTML formatting.

Do the following once and you can always click on the shortcut for all future replies:

*Reply/Reply All* an example email. Go to the *Format Text* tab. Right-click on the *HTML* option in the *Format* panel. Click on *Add to Quick Access Toolbar*.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the problem is determining whether or not you are forwarding/replying to emails and including the referenced email as an attachment or part of the email itself. If your issue is that its being received by gmail, etc as a .eml file you've likely selected to forward emails as attachments within outlook. This function translates the referenced email into a .eml file which is not easily read by a browser based email client.

Simply go to File > Options > Mail > Replies and Forwards and change the settings to include the referenced email within the email rather than as an attachment or any of the other options.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found how to do this.

File - Options - Trust Center - Trust Center Options - Email Security - Check Read all standard mail in plain text.

This forces all the replies to be in plain text.

Alternatively (and what I personally prefer), in Group Policy Editor:

User Configuration - Administrative Templates - Microsoft Outlook 2016 - Outlook Options - Preferences - Email Options - Read e-mail as plain text - Enabled.

Answer (score -1):

I added a shortcut to the Quick Access Toolbar to "Clear All Formatting". Then, when I reply/reply all to any email, I can select all the text in my reply and simply click the button to format exactly as my default style set.

You can add this shortcut to the Quick Access Toolbar as follows:
Reply/Reply All to an email. 
Go to the Format Text tab. 
Click on the Styles drop-down icon (bottom left).
Right-click on Clear Formatting.
Click on Add to Quick Access Toolbar.

Comment: While this answer contains the word "format" it does not actually answer the question, nor is it really about the same thing the question is about. Please read questions carefully and make sure your answer applies before posting.